# Iterating through unsequenced object in angular 9

Tags: typescript, angular9

[Object structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNqQ0.png) I want to iterate through one complex object where, I want all values in ngbtypeahead, before that I'm not able to get those values from this complex object just because keys are different.

```
***> Special Tests: {
                       244: "Immunohistochemistry (IHC)", 
                       245: "Flowcytometry", 
                       246: "PET scan"
                     }
     TUMOUR MARKERS: {
                       24: "CEA",  
                       25: "PSA", 
                       26: "AFP",  
                       27: "CA 125"
                     } ***
```

Comment: Hi, can you reformat the code in your question? It is not well-formatted and hence difficult to understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing here that your options should be `"Immunohistochemistry (IHC)", "Flowcytometry", "PET scan", "CEA", "PSA", "AFP", "CA 125" ...`.
So you need values of the complex object's values:

```
const options = Object.values(yourComplexObject)
  .reduce((options, subObject) => [...options, ...Object.values(subObject)], [])
```

Comment: Yes ,You are correct  I need "Immunohistochemistry (IHC)", "Flowcytometry", "PET scan", "CEA", "PSA", "AFP", "CA 125"  . These all as a Options but  Object is coming from get api So , Struggling to get data from that object.Should I have to use reduce()??

Comment: `reduce` here is used to merge arrays of options from each sub-object into a single array. there are other ways to do it, of course. What exactly is the problem? Can you `console.log` your object to see that it's there? maybe you are missing `await ...` ? Can't help without more input from you

Comment: object structure is uploaded in questions section : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNqQ0.png